# Visual Studio 2010 Freezes when using TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

When I try to perform most actions in TFS or a project using TFS, such as add a file to the project the main interface freezes.

I have looked at the call stack, and it appears to be in a deadlock while checking to see if a project is active.

I have tried downloading a completely fresh copy of the code, but that did not help.

I am using VS2010 with SP1 installed.

This is the top of the call stack for the Main Thread when frozen after refreshing my Pending Changes

```
ntdll.dll!_ZwWaitForSingleObject@12()  + 0x15 bytes
ntdll.dll!_ZwWaitForSingleObject@12()  + 0x15 bytes
Tfsprovider.dll!NVseeFC::CCriticalSection::Lock()  + 0x1d bytes
Tfsprovider.dll!CSccManager::fIsSolutionFolderProject()  + 0x3b bytes
Tfsprovider.dll!CSccManager::IsActive()  + 0x153 bytes
Tfsprovider.dll!CVsSccUI::Exec_icmdSccRefreshStatus()  + 0xbd bytes
Tfsprovider.dll!CVsCommandTargetMap<CVsSccUI,IOleCommandTarget>::Exec()  + 0x6a bytes
Tfsprovider.dll!CVsCommandTarget<NVseePkgsVssProvider::CGridBarDialog,IxNull>::Exec()  + 0x26 bytes
Tfsprovider.dll!CVsSccPackage::Exec()  + 0xa9 bytes
Tfsprovider.dll!CVsSccHatHelper::RefreshStatus()  + 0x3c bytes
[Managed to Native Transition]
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VssProvider.RefreshStatus() + 0x35 bytes
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.ToolWindowPendingCheckinsForm.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.IPendingCheckinHost.RefreshPendingCheckins() + 0x69 bytes
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.dll!Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.PendingCheckinsChannelControl.OnRefreshPendingCheckins() + 0x3d bytes
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.dll!Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.PendingCheckinsChannelControl.RefreshSelectedChannel() + 0x22 bytes
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.CommandHandlerPendingCheckins.Refresh_Exec(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.CommandHandler handler, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.CommandHandler.Command command, int commandId) + 0x13 bytes
(Other calls removed, they don't look relevant)
```

Has anyone else had this issue, or know of a fix for it?

UPDATE:
The interface comes back to life after waiting about 8 minutes. During this time the the TFS server sends me about 60,000 packets of data over the network.

UPDATE 2:
I fixed this by manually recreating the SLN file.

Comment: You do have TFS 2010 SP1 installed, correct?

Answer (score 3):

This blocking behaviour was unfortunately a 'by design' problem. In Visual Studio 2010, Team Explorer (and a bunch of other VS components) would perform many operations synchronously and block the UI thread in the Visual Studio shell while they were processing, especially on source control operations.

Making source control operations asynchronous was one of the design goals in Visual Studio 2012 - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/09/01/wrapping-up-tfs-11-version-control-improvements.aspx