# 1050x1680 resolution causes Visual Studio 2010 locks up when interfacing with TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, screen-resolution

I just added a third monitor to my system (NEC E222W) which my NVidia GeForce 9500 GT card is able to rotate such that I get 1050x1680 resolution.  However, when using this mode Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel) consistently locks up (grabbing 50% of the CPU) until I kill it whenever I interact with TFS.  I can work in VS 2010 until I try to do anything with TFS.

I can open up Visual Studio without issues on my other two monitors and check stuff out, etc., but the minute I move the application to my 1050x1680 monitor and start the TFS dialog, the application hangs.

Anyone have this issue?  I'm pretty current on the NVidia driver (191.07) and Windows XP SP 3 is current with Microsoft Update.  I'm running under a non-administrator account.

Internet has not been helpful.  The only thing I found was this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vseditor/thread/ce9134aa-b444-49e8-99f2-01b67404156a

This: [Visual Studio 2010 Freezes when using TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842981/visual-studio-2010-freezes-when-using-tfs) is unrelated.

I am able to fire up VS 2010 on the 1050x1680 monitor, work, then shift the existing instance over to another monitor to interface with TFS (check in/out) and then shift the application back to the 1050x1680 monitor successfully.  I strongly suspect something is broken with the TFS checkout dialog window.

Comment: That is an incredibly strange bug. Unfortunately I doubt anyone on SO will be able to answer it given the specifics involved. Have you tried attaching a debugger and seeing what the call stack is?  That may clue someone into the problem

Comment: Or file a connect bug...

Comment: FYI, freezes also happen w/ VS 2010 Tools/Options/Source Control/VS TFS/Configure User Tools

Comment: Naturally, when filing a connect bug, VS 2010 isn't an option...

Comment: Answered my own question.  The solution was (naturally) update NVidia driver to current (6.14.12.6099).  Hopefully someone may find this useful.